# Java Regex: extract a substring from a pattern occurring multiple times

Tags: java, regex

Sorry, if this is a lame question, I am quite new to Java development and regex patterns.

Basically I have a long string which has multiple occurrences of substrings like `InstanceId: i-1234XYAadsadd,` and I want to extract out the `i-1234XYAadsadd` part in an `ArrayList` using regex. Please help with the correct regular expression here.

```
//instanceResultString is the actual string containing occurences of pattern
List<String> instanceIdList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("InstanceId:[.]*,").matcher(instanceResultString);
    while(matcher.find())
        instanceIdList.add(matcher.group());
```

Comment: Maybe `"InstanceId:\\s*(\\S+),"` and access `.group(1)`

Comment: I guess this will include the whitespace(s) after `InstanceId:`, I want to exclude those

Comment: Ideone is too slow now, can't show the demo. Try `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("InstanceId:\\s*(\\S+),").matcher(instanceResultString);
     while(matcher.find())
         instanceIdList.add(matcher.group(1));`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/LaFmXw

Comment: Great, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I posted an answer with the pattern explanation. If you need more assistance, please let me know. Also note that `[.]*` matches zero or more literal *dots*, so your pattern was doomed to "malfunction".

Answer (score 1):

The only point here is that the strings you want to match are made of non-whitespace characters. The `\S` pattern matches a non-whitespace char.

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/LaFmXw):

```
String instanceResultString = "InstanceId: i-1234XYAadsadd, More text: InstanceId: u-222tttt, dde InstanceId: i-8999UIIIgjkkd,";
List<String> instanceIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("InstanceId:\\s*(\\S+),").matcher(instanceResultString);
while(matcher.find())
    instanceIdList.add(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(instanceIdList); // Demo line
// => [i-1234XYAadsadd, u-222tttt, i-8999UIIIgjkkd]
```

Where

- `InstanceId:` - a literal `InstanceId:` text
- `\\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\\S+)` - Group 1 (we grab these contents with `.group(1)`) capturing 1 or more (but as many as possible) non-whitespace symbols
- `,`  - a comma.

Comment: Note that you might also consider `InstanceId:\\s*(\\S+)\\b` pattern to match on the last word boundary after as many non-whitespace symbols as there are after `InstanceId:` + zero or more whitespaces.